# Recursion limit for NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, performance-tuning, recursion

I have a fairly complex equation containing many terms, I can use the `NDSolve` for solving the differential equation for lesser terms (6400ish). But can't do it for let's say 10^4 terms, due to the error "$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded." I modified the code (provided below) it to have a higher recursion limit, but it still treats the recursion limit to be 1024. Can someone please help me with the situation?

```
Clear[x]; (x = 
  x /. First[
    Block[{$RecursionLimit = 10^4},x= 
     NDSolve[{x'[t] == eqn, x[0] == x0}, Fraction[x], {t, 0, tF}, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 30, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
      MaxSteps -> 10^5]]]);
```

Comment: Is there any chance that you could determine that your equation works out to n terms and fails at n+1 terms? And then look at exactly what that n+1 term is? If you can do that then move that term to the end and see if  your equation possibly then works out to m terms and fails at m+1. And repeat until you have identified and isolated all your problem terms. Then show us what those problem terms are and how they are very different from all your non-problem terms.

Comment: What's the definition of `eqn`?

Comment: Try it without the `x=`, which occurs in two places. Defining `x` in terms of itself is a good way to get infinite recursion.

Comment: What's the definition of `Fraction[x]`?

Comment: Thank you @Goofy, this solved the recursion problem, but for higher number of terms I am still getting stiffness issue or NDSolve failing and suggesting to use residual method. Bill the terms are of the form $\sum a\sin(\gamma x)e^{b(t-tf)}$, only a, b and $\gamma$ change.